# Transparently forward local port to remote server

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have StatsD daemon running on a remote server (`x.x.x.x`) at `8125`. I would like to forward `127.0.0.1:8125` to `x.x.x.x:8125`.

I have already tried running the following on localhost

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 8125 -j DNAT --to x.x.x.x:8125
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 8125 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:8125
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d x.x.x.x -j MASQUERADE
```

But it is not forwarding correctly.

```
echo "test.test.test:1|c" | nc -w 1 -u localhost 8125
```

Fails with error
    nc: Write error: Connection refused

```
echo "test.test.test:1|c" | nc -w 1 -u 127.0.0.1 8125
```

Fails without any error

```
echo "test.test.test:1|c" | nc -w 1 -u x.x.x.x 8125
```

Works correctly

Also, will such a port forwarding cause any security issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible.

Packets generated by local processes are not involved in the forwarding plan.

As a consequence you won't be able to use `PREROUTING` and `FORWARD` chains in the tables locally generated packets will go through, but only `OUTPUT` (in `raw/mangle/nat/filter` tables) and `POSTROUTING` (in `mangle/nat` tables) chains **while the routing decision is already made and you can't change it**.

In fact with your current iptables setup your rules will do the following considering your use case :

- First rule : unreached.
- Second rule : DNAT locally generated packets to `x.x.x.x` on the loopback interface.
- Third rule : Masquerade packets going trough your loopback interface with the IP address of your loopback interface.

So the result is : local packets will try to reach `x.x.x.x:8125` on your loopback interface.

This [netfilter diagram](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png) can help you understand the location of locally generated packets in the global flow.

Comment: Thank you Xavier. My knowledge in networking is very limited, and I couldn't understand much from the the netfilter diagram. So, what are my options to forward local udp port to a remote server? SSH Tunneling?

Comment: @JoyceBabu You can do that directly with a fifo and netcat : `nc -ul -p 8125 < /tmp/fifo | nc -u x.x.x.x 8125 > /tmp/fifo`

Comment: This is for a live web server. Would such a setup open up any security issues? Also, will it stay open permanently if I add it to cron to run at @reboot using  `nohup`?