# Forward a local port to a non ssh-capable server

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to make a port (for example 9876) available on a linux server (Bob) for other hosts to connect to.
As the target machine (Alice) that serves port 9876 is a micro-controller hence has no ssh capabilities (or at least, none that I have access to (which, I must add, is only for the best, to prevent people like me fiddling with it)), I was thinking of using a ssh-tunnel with remote forwarding on Bob to make port 9876 available on the server Bob.

(The reason I'm posting this question for which i've found an answer, is because I have a feeling there might be a more elegant solution.
Somehow tunneling to localhost feels untidy.)

Answer (score 2):

[3proxy](https://3proxy.ru/) is included in some distributions. You can use the [`tcppm`](https://3proxy.ru/doc/man8/tcppm.8.html) (TCP Port Mapper) command to listen on a local port and forward it to another host. Something like this should work:

```
tcppm 9876 Alice-ip 9876
```

Play with the options for logging etc as you need.

Comment: Very straightforward and elegant solution. But if security is a concern, SSH is still needed when the protocol involved (via port 9876 in this case) it's not encrypted

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution (which I didn't try out) using `iptables` here [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/647783/transparently-forward-local-port-to-remote-server)

I ended up using this solution on Bob:
`ssh -R9876:<Alice-ip-address>:9876 user-on-Bob@localhost`

So now I could use the application to connect to its default port on the server Bob instead of directly to the micro-controller Alice

Answer (score 0):

Any load balancer type forwarding solution could work.

For example, if you can put it behind a Linux box, Linux IP Virtual Server implements a layer 4 load balancer. See the manual for `ipvsadm`.